# handling conflict in regex python

Tags: python, regex

I am creating a script that extracts tracking numbers from an email account. The tracking could be provided by ups, fedex, or usps. I'm running into the issue that the UPS regex is picking up a USPS tracking number.

For example, my UPS regex is:

```
\b(1Z ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{2} ?[0-9A-Z]{3,4} ?[0-9A-Z]{3,4} ?[0-9A-Z]|[\dT]\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d|\d\d\d ?\d\d\d ?\d\d\d|\d{22,34}|\d{18}|MI[0-9]{6}[0-9A-Z]{1,22})\b
```

while my USPS regex is:

```
\b(9[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{2})\b
```

An example of what is being matched by both: `9405436252332194262342`

I'm not sure how to handle this conflict. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: If `9405436252332194262342` is both a valid UPS number and a valid USPS number, then there is no way to tell. This has nothing to do with python or regex or  computers at all.

Comment: There is no way to do that if the same code can be used by both companies. UPS regex `[\dT]\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d` alternative [matches the `9405436252332194262342` string](https://regex101.com/r/LBASBS/1) and unless there is a differentiator, you will just get the same codes twice. You may check if the code has already been matched, and probably, if it was matched at the same location.

Comment: You can try checking for other keywords in the email to try to guess which it is, like a Bayesian spam filter does. These classifiers are usually not 100% accurate, but it might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Another idea that I had is to test each captured number across each of the shipping apis. based on the response, i can also capture the tracking status, if the number is correct for that company.